# How do these partial derivative and derivative terms relate?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

From the top line, [this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6oWF.png) jumps to the integration and evaluation of the function. I'm not sure how the partial of $t$ and $dt$ play in the integration to give $(s,t)$ before evaluation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the fundamental theorem of calculus you know and love. In the same way that you compute a partial derivative and ignore other variables and differentiate the one you care about, when you integrate with respect to one variable, you ignore the others.

The first line of this is saying: "I am integrating with respect to t something (the stuff in brackets) that was differentiated with respect to t," giving you by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the bracketed quantity. Then since it is a definite integral, you are just evaluating your antiderivative at the end points.

To perhaps better address your question, the partial $\frac{\partial d}{\partial s}$ is in the brackets and was therefore "previously" differentiated with respect to t, so integration undoes its t differentiation as well.

Comment: I get it :). Thanks!